# Sparse Iteration in Chapel

Tags: loops, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix, hpc, chapel

Given an array `M:[sps]` over a `sps = sparse subdomain(dom)` where `dom: domain(n)`, I know I can iterate densely over the k​th​​ dimension with `for j in M.domain.dim(k) {...}`. How would I define an analogous loop that visits only populated locations in k such that if `M.domain.dim(k) = {1..N}`, but there are only m populated indices in k, the loop only formally generates m iterations rather than N?

Would the way to do this be to iterate over the whole sparse domain with an iterand that only references one index? (i.e. `for (i,j) in spsDom { var idx = i }`)

Comment: Would you mind to formulate the MCVE-code in >>> https://tio.run/##pc9NC4JAEAbg@/6KwZNCKNHNpUNogVB68BJUh023EnRd9qOI6LdvlmLUrXwvM@/lYSY7EU5LY6CLlhSW5FprFaQYZTU7FEdohlTwTxhMYYL76nmo234gSZisZlHcSDcYuy4bIRiUpzGQuOM3cCaiPTPlREjaHuuDfDWQep/XFSmY3f/hQF4RzmkOQWo7X9@sfdh8SDsQlJQYoYsoFC0bx4riReNTpTmESTzfMgscbMwD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much of an answer to this question beyond [my previous answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46248469/6815267).  The quick summary is that there is an undocumented iterator, `dimIter()` that can be used to iterate over the efficient dimension of a sparse domain stored with a 2D CSR/CSC format, but there is not an official interface for doing this for all sparse domains today (as of version 1.16 of Chapel).

I think the way we'd want to express this ultimately would be to [support slicing of sparse domains](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/8023) and then iterate over that slice.